# How to add unfiltered_html capability

Tags: wordpress

When posting html content below it posts fine with the admin, but any other user it strips all HTML tags

```
$my_post = array('post_title' => $title,
                         'post_content' => $content,                
                         'post_category' => array(520),
                         'post_status' => 'Publish',
                         'post_name'     => $url
                        );

  $result = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Is there a way to allow any user to post HTML tags.

Comment: are they wrapping the code in `code` tags? i.e. highlight the code in the editor and then click the "code" button.

Comment: not sure what you mean - so probably not

Answer (score -1):

I found that if I use this before the code, it works.

```
$sub_role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
$sub_role->add_cap( 'unfiltered_html', true );
```

Comment: Really bad idea to give unfiltered_html cap to subscriber or as implied, to everyone.